# Storing phrases from a string into a list

Tags: python, list

I've found this bit of code that works exactly as intended, yet im puzzled as to why.

The idea is to extract information from each line (without spaces or extra tabulation symbols).

The code i found is the following:

```
def extract_information(line: str) -> list:

return [phrase.strip() for phrase in line.split('  ') if phrase]
```

And it works! But since it's a one-liner, im having a hard time trying to decipher it, im used to fully written out loops.

```
Ie.

print(extract_information("Marni             FIGHTS FOR LIFE           Old Shack            Will rule the kingdom"))
```

Should become:

```
['Marni', 'FIGHTS FOR LIFE', 'Old Shack', 'Will rule the kingdom']
```

Anyone has a clue about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supports something called **List comprehension**.

**Summary**

> It consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for
>   clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. The expressions can be
>   anything, meaning you can put in all kinds of objects in lists.

**Behind the scenes**

Thus, you can read the above expression this way:

```
[return something for something in listofsomethings if something exists ]
```

*Note that the above expression is only for educational purposes and is not valid in any way.*

Therefore in your particular case, it could be translated to this:

```
for phrase in line.split('  '):
    if phrase:
        phrase.strip()
```

So as you can see, it does exactly what you expect it to do. Both do the exact same thing but list comprehension is generally considered as more pythonic.

Answer (score -2):

It's list comprehension. Run something simple like this to see how it works. It's basically a way to loop through a list in a succinct way.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y=[a*2 for a in x]
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but it's plain to see that your answer does not really address OP's doubts.... sure they need a list comp, but `[a* 2 for a in x]` will not get them there. If you are willing to help, but not willing to address the question at length, a comment would be more suitable.

Comment: He's asking why the one liner works. I'm not attempting to fix his code or solve anything, just help him see what is going on.

Comment: Hmm, indeed I did misread, but your answer still does not explain why the code works. Just that it uses a list comprhension... nothing more.

Comment: A complete explanation of list comprehension seems a little beyond the scope of an SO answer. That's what the docs are for. All this was meant to do was help him figure it out himself.